# How to Show three dots at the end of "AppCompatEditText" when it is in out of focus

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

i am using AppCompatEditText I set

```xml
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:editable="false"
      android:maxLines="1"
```

However, the text truncation is not displayed at the text's end. Are there any properties I might have overlooked for properly truncating the text? thanks

```xml
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
      android:id="@+id/tvCheckListName"
      style="@style/text_sub_heading_16_medium"
      android:layout_width="190dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:background="@color/transparent"
      android:clickable="false"
      android:enabled="false"
      android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
      android:focusable="false"
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:editable="false"
      android:maxLines="1"
      android:cursorVisible="false"
      android:maxLength="120"
      android:text="jsdkfhdjsjfkhskdjafhjlsdfhjkasdfhjasdklfhldksahfkjldasfjkdsahf"
      android:imeOptions="actionDone"
      android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/_6sdp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.063"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvSelector"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In the **AppCompatEditText** with properties sets already truncate the text at the end (*android:ellipsize="end" and android:singleLine="true"*). But it's not working as expected.

Look into your **text style** that is not override the ellipsize behaviour, also that content is long enough to be truncated.

In carefully looking at your code, there might be other attributes interfere with the ellipsize behavior, such as android:maxLength="120" or any custom attributes in your style that might affect text truncation.

Comment: <style name="text_sub_heading_16_medium">
        <item name="android:lineHeight">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_medium</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_black_text</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|start</item>

    </style>